# Is there a Visual Studio option to toggle between two actions with one key combination?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, ide

I'd like to use just one key combination to toggle between two actions in Visual Studio. Is this possible? Specifically, can I use `ctrl+/` to comment code, and then press it again to uncomment code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. You can, if that's enough for you, set various bind to **CTRL+H**, **ALT+H** and **CTRL+ALT+H**.

(You can also play with **UPPERCASE**)